# How to turn first couple lines of elements in file to 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, list

So what I'm trying to do is basically turn make a 3x3 table from the data file. For example if the data file is given some much like

```
0 5 2
7 8 4
1 6 3
4
U 2
D 2
L 1
D 2
```

I need a table of first 3x3 so some thing like

```
                                               0 5 2 
                                               7 8 4
                                               1 6 3
```

I tried it my way

```
def readfile(x):
    torusSquare=[]
    file= open(x)
    count=0
    while count<3:
        line = file.readline()
        line=line.rstrip('\n').split(' ')
        vals=[]
        for val in line:
            vals.append(int(val))
        torusSquare.append(vals)
        count+=1
```

Although I do get an output of

```
[[0, 5, 2]]
[[0, 5, 2], [7, 8, 4]]
[[0, 5, 2], [7, 8, 4], [1, 6, 3]]
```

but when I try calling `torusSquare` into another function for instance `printArray(toursSquare)`
below is the function

```
def printArray(torusSquare):
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            print(torusSquare[i][j],' ',end=' ')
        print()
```

i get an error

```
    print(torusSquare[i][j],' ',end=' ')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: In your own words, why do you expect the `torusSquare` that you create in `readfile` to have anything to do with the `torusSquare` received by `printArray` as a parameter? Also, if you got the correct output from the code that tries to read the file, then your question is - obviously - not actually about how to read the file, it's elsewhere in your code. Please ask about the actual problem you are actually having. Also please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help us help you.

Comment: The function printArray basically suppose to turn [[0, 5, 2], [7, 8, 4], [1, 6, 3]] to an actual array which would be a 3x3 table

Comment: We don't have built-in arrays in Python; we have lists - and your `[[0, 5, 2], [7, 8, 4], [1, 6, 3]]` result is already that thing, which you can use perfectly well as a 3x3 table. Everything that you show in the `printArray` code can be done with the `torusSquare` value that you computed. The problem is that your code is not actually causing `printArray` to use that value. You probably need to review how function calls work, what `return` means and how it works, etc.

Comment: @moonahmad Do you return `torusSquare` from `readfile` ?

Comment: But I can only tell you what's wrong in the rest of the code if you actually show the relevant portion of that code. Again, please read the links I gave you, in order to understand how to ask the question properly.

Comment: @AndrejKesely yes I do

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thanks for your suggestion. I'll def have a look at the links you send

Comment: @KarlKnechtel would you mind giving me a hint of how I can I use toruSquare to do everything that can be done from printArray

Comment: ... that's not what I said. What I said is that `torusSquare` is already in the correct format to do the things that you're trying to do with it in `printArray`. Therefore, the problem is not with how you create `torusSquare`. The problem is with how you try to pass it around in your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('your_file.txt', sep= ' ',header=None, nrows=3)
array = df.to_numpy().astype(int)

print(array)
#
[[0 5 2]
 [7 8 4]
 [1 6 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I run your code like this:

```
def readfile(x):
    torusSquare=[]
    file= open(x)
    count=0
    while count<3:
        line = file.readline()
        line = line.rstrip('\n').split(' ')
        vals=[]
        for val in line:
            vals.append(int(val))
        torusSquare.append(vals)
        count+=1

    if count==3:
        for i in range(count):
            for j in range(count):
                print(torusSquare[i][j],' ',end=' ')
        print()

    return torusSquare

def printArray(torusSquare):
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            print(torusSquare[i][j],' ',end=' ')
        print()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    ts = readfile('data.txt')

    printArray(ts)
```

It produces exactly the output you were expecting:

```
0   5   2
7   8   4
1   6   3
```

In the function readfile(x) I added the following line:

```
return torusSquare
```

That makes the function returning the torusSquare list (so when you call the function it "spits out" the return value, in your case torusSquare). Then you can assign it to any arbitrary variable name (like "ts") as shown below:

```
ts = readfile('data.txt')
```

This you can then send to the printArray function.

Comment: After the count+=1 I had added                                                                                      
           if count==3:
            for i in range(count):
                for j in range(count):
                    print(torusSquare[i][j],' ',end=' ')
                print()

Comment: That also seems to work. I updated my answer. Maybe the intendation was wrong? Although this does not make sense, only for debugging.